# Check if Array exists in JSON file - iOS

Tags: ios, json, cocoa-touch, object, nsarray

I have an iOS application which parses a JSON feed provided by Google Plus. This JSON feed contains links, titles, etc for posts on a Google Plus profile.

The JSON file in certain parts has an array called "attachments" and that array has the image URL which I am parsing.

The problem is that that array is not always present, so sometime its available with the image URL and sometime its not even there.

As a result of this, when I parse for the image URL my iOS application crashes because the array it is looking for is not always present.

So how can I test to see if the array is present before deciding to parse for the image URL. I tried to make a simple if-statement, but it doesn't seem to work. Here it is:

```
if ([[[episodes objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"object"] valueForKey:@"attachments"] == [NSNull null]) {
            NSLog("No image to parse.");
        }

else {
    // parse image link 
}
```

Here is the JSON file:

```
  {


"kind": "plus#activity",
   "etag": "\"9Q4kEgczRt3gWehMocqSxXqUhYo/uQcxIDsySGhlI5hMFHcxjuBhM9k\"",
   "title": "",
   "published": "2013-02-24T22:30:25.159Z",
   "updated": "2013-02-24T22:30:25.159Z",
   "id": "z13jgdihsvnytdttc23hxdz5ypfsjnzsb",
   "url": "https://plus.google.com/102757352146004417544/posts/7psQLdwS2F7",
   "actor": {
    "id": "102757352146004417544",
    "displayName": "Daniel Sadjadian",
    "url": "https://plus.google.com/102757352146004417544",
    "image": {
     "url": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-EF0LibpIsEY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAALQ/2nt32bqYBtM/photo.jpg?sz=50"
    }
   },
   "verb": "post",
   "object": {
    "objectType": "note",
    "content": "",
    "url": "https://plus.google.com/102757352146004417544/posts/7psQLdwS2F7",
    "replies": {
     "totalItems": 0,
     "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z13jgdihsvnytdttc23hxdz5ypfsjnzsb/comments"
    },
    "plusoners": {
     "totalItems": 0,
     "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z13jgdihsvnytdttc23hxdz5ypfsjnzsb/people/plusoners"
    },
    "resharers": {
     "totalItems": 0,
     "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z13jgdihsvnytdttc23hxdz5ypfsjnzsb/people/resharers"
    },
    "attachments": [
     {
      "objectType": "video",
      "displayName": "SGU - The Game Has Changed!",
      "content": "Send this video to your friends to spread the word about the upcoming SyFy marathon. This very well may be our last chance to save the show. If you're in the...",
      "url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WtHusm7Yzd4",
      "image": {
       "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/z9shhK2d39jM2P-AOLMkqP2KMG2DjipCWlcPeVPaRvHkfj-nmxkxqZfntAVMoV88ZOuroRHIvG4qs-K0SaMjQw=w506-h284-n",
       "type": "image/jpeg",
       "height": 284,
       "width": 506
      },
      "embed": {
       "url": "http://www.youtube.com/v/WtHusm7Yzd4?version=3&autohide=1",
       "type": "application/x-shockwave-flash"
      }
     }
    ]
   },
   "provider": {
    "title": "Google+"
   },
   "access": {
    "kind": "plus#acl",
    "description": "Public",
    "items": [
     {
      "type": "public"
     }
    ]
   }
  },
```

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Just assign that to array and check the `array` is `nil`.

```
NSMutableArray *attachments = [[[episodes objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"object"] valueForKey:@"attachments"];
if (!attachments) {
            NSLog("No image to parse.");
        }
```

This will work.

Comment: `[NSNull null]` is a singleton, no need for `isEqual:`.

Comment: OMG.. I just forgot that.. Thanks @Kevin.

Comment: @kevin I cheat and use == sometimes but is that actually guaranteed by the API?

Comment: @nielsbot You should not use == to compare objective objects. That's the idea. If I am wrong, just share your thought.

Comment: You can use `==` to compare object pointers. (i.e. "are these the exact same instance?") `isEqual:` is to determine if two objects are equivalent based on their contents.

Comment: @nielsbot It's guaranteed to be a singleton, so I'm pretty sure that guarantees the `==`.

Comment: yeah it says so right in the docs. in the case you could use `obj == kCFNull` too :)

Comment: theoretically you have to check for both `null` and `nil`.  those both mean no attachment. hence my category suggestion.

Comment: @nielsbot ok I understand. Your category makes sense. If the array returns NSNull or NSObject, it will call the appropriate method from category and return the nil or self and then if statement evaluate to run it. In my answer, it won't check if it is NSNull. So it may crash somewhere. right?

Comment: Thank you @DineshRaja your solution worked perfectly. You have saved me from a good hour of not understanding what was wrong.

Comment: I guess you could also just use `if ( attachments && attachments != [ NSNull null ] ) { /* handle attachments */ }`

Comment: @nielsbot I have a doubt. Will json can send `[NSNull null]` objects?? I hope it is just a plain string and won't be `NSNull` singleton ever.

Comment: Thank you @nielsbot I didn't know that before. Good to know that now. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem (please post your error details) but when dealing with JSON, I like to use a category `IfNullThenNil`. Your code would look like:

```
if ( [ [ episodes[index] valueForKeyPath:@"object.attachments" ] ifNullThenNil ]
{
    // parse image link
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"No image to parse.\n");
}
```

Here's the category on `NSObject`/`NSNull`

```
@implementation NSObject (IfNullThenNil)
-(id)ifNullThenNil
{
    return self ;
}
@end

@implementation NSNull (IfNullThenNil)
-(id)ifNullThenNil
{
    return nil ;
}
@end
```